# find a object via array object value mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, collections

So I have a collection:

```js
{
 _id: 1,
 array: [{id:1,something: "anything"}]
},
{
 _id: 2,
 array: [{id:2,something: "anything"}]
}
```

I want to find the object that has a array that includes the object with the id `1`, how do I do that with mongodb's .findOne()?

Answer (score 0):

You can find using $elemMatch.

db.collection_name.findOne(
{ array : { $elemMatch : { id : 1 } } }
)

This is another way you can also find using this simple query
db.collection_name.findOne(
{ "array.id" : 1 }
)